# How would I extract odd-numbered pages from pdf using the command line on a mac

Tags: command-line, pdf

The file is too big to do a manual extract using Preview.  It can be done manually in Chrome by pasting in 1,2,3... in the print dialog, but this is tedious.  Is there a command line tool to extract alternate pages (odd or even) from a pdf file?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [sejda-console](http://sejda.org/) (GNU Affero Public License 3.0 open source license):

```
./bin/sejda-console extractpages -f /input/file.pdf --predefinedPages odd -o odd.pdf
```

I'm one of the developers in the project.

There's also a web interface: https://www.sejda.com/extract-pdf-pages

Comment: Many thanks for your help and efforts for this important project!  I was unable to get the command line interface to work. The documentation at https://github.com/torakiki/sejda/wiki/Getting-Started talks about a bin directory, but there was not one in either the top level of the extracted tar file, nor in the sejda-console subdirectory.  How do I proceed to install it on my mac?  The web interface works well, but is not as convenient for me as having a working command line interface.

Comment: I've updated the download link: http://sejda.org/ You should download a zip file, that when extracted contains a bin folder.